# What is use of `""+` in setText

Tags: java

I have an example:

```
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(firstno.getText());
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(secondno.getText());
 int num3 = num1+num2;
 result.setText(""+num3);
```

what is use of `""` in `result.setText(""+num3);`

Comment: it converts the integer to a string without using something like `String.valueOf(num3)`, it is shorter.

Comment: `setText` expects a String argument. This is how you make a string from the `int num3`.

Comment: because `result.setText` does not accept an int

Comment: setText accept the string arguement.  In java, String + number = String.

Comment: A better way would be `result.setText(String.valueOf(num3));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a (very) lazy way to convert `int` to `String`.

```
result.setText(num3);
```

Does not work because `setText()` requires a `String` and not an `int`. Better would be to use this:

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(num3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus operator ("+") for instances of String class is overridden and leads to concatenation. [See spec.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method. String conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by Object and inherited by all classes in Java. For additional information on string concatenation and conversion, see Gosling, Joy, and Steele, The Java Language Specification.

So in your case, your second object is an instance of Integer, so to concatenate an empty String **""** and the number **num3** conversion of num3 to String should happen first.

The result of the concatenation is a new string which contains a string representation of your num3.

Comment: You interpret the text incorrectly. There is no autoboxing involved. What the doc says is that it's the equivalent of `new StringBuilder().append("").append(num3).toString()`. [`StringBuilder.append(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-int-) exists and doesn't involve autoboxing at all!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire thanks for your comment. Indeed there is an overloaded version of "StringBuilder.append(int)"  which is optimized especially for this purpose.